# Calling javascript functions in windbg breakpoint-commands

Tags: javascript, c++, debugging, windbg, breakpoints

I have a windbg-issue concerning the execution
of a javascript-function as a breakpoint-command.
This observation was made in windbg Preview 10.0.17030.1002 
and also in recent versions of windbg
when debugging a native x86 C++ program on Windows 10.

## Test Setup

In my javascript-file dbg_test.js I have the following function:

```
function test()
{
   var ctl = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control;
   host.diagnostics.debugLog(">>> Test\n");
   ctl.ExecuteCommand("g");
}
```

In windbg, I load the javascript-provider, load my dbg_test.js script 
and define a breakpoint-command to call this javascript-function:

```
  bs 0 "dx @$scriptContents.test()"
```

## Expected Behavior

The string ">>> Test" is shown in the output-pane of the command-window 
**everytime** when breakpoint 0 is hit.
The debugger resumes execution.

## Observed Behavior

The output ">>> Test" is shown only the first time
when breakpoint 0 is hit.
Subsequently hitting breakpoint 0 does not
produce any output.

## Remarks

1) Doing the analogous test with "old style" windbg-commands works fine:

```
bs 0 ".printf \">>> Test\\n\\n\";g;"
```

but **only** after ending and restarting windbg

2) The same behavior is shown when I move the code of function "test" to the function "invokeScript()" and define the breakpoint-command via

```
bs 0 ".scriptrun d:\\dbg_scripts\\dbg_test.js"
```

3) Running the script from the windbg-command-line works.

4) Calling javascript-functions as in the test-scenario above worked in previous versions of windbg.

5) It seems that the statement

```
ctl.ExecuteCommand("g");
```

is the  crucial one: If I comment out this statement, then the breakpoint 
   is hit every time and the output from

```
host.diagnostics.debugLog(">>> Test\n");
```

is shown on each hit of the breakpoint.
   Of course, I have to resume the execution manually by pressing F5 or entering the command "g"

## Questions

1. Can someone reproduce this issue ?
2. Is it legal to use javascript-functions in this way or am I doing something wrong here ?

Your feedback is greatly appreciated!

Kind/Best regards!

Comment: sending a gc should work and it is documented too  it worked for me in 14951   but it doesnt work on 16299 so it appears to be a bug try reporting it to windbgfb@microsoft.com

Comment: @blabb: your comments are absolutely correct and thank you for verifying that the issue exists in recent windbg versions. I already posted the issue to windbgfb@microsoft.com but did never get a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you did. I was able to somewhat bypass the problem by declaring a script global variable

```
var lines = [];
```

and pushing log messages to this array rather than debug printing them:

```
lines.push(">>> Test");
```

In order to see the lines, I created a function

```
function print_lines() {
   for (var line of lines) {
      host.diagnostics.debugLog(line + "\n");
   }
   lines = [];
}
```

which I called from the prompt like so

```
dx @$scriptContents.print_lines();
```

I know that this is not really answering your question, but it might still be helpful for someone else that faces the same problem.